# Is there a surjective group homomorphism from $D_5 \to \mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is there a surjective group homomorphism from $D_5 \to \mathbb{Z}_5$?

I think not because:

Generator of $D_5$ is $<\rho, \mu >$ where $\rho$ is rotation and $\mu$ is rotation. I need to match $\rho \to 1$ because $\rho ^5 = e$. That means $5*1$ mod $5 $ should be 0.

But there's no element for $\mu$ that satisfies $2*a = 0 $ mod $5$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}_5$

Is this correct thought?

Comment: Keep in mind too that $D_5$ has order 10 while the other has order 5.  The order of the subgroup has to make sense as a factor.  You also have to contend with the fact that $Z$ is abelian while dihedral is not

Comment: Any such map must send $xy$ and $yx$ to the same value in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary elements of $D_5.$ This is what CogitoErgoCogitoSum was alluding to. So, all commutators are in the kernel of the map, if that helps you any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\varphi: D_5\to\mathbb{Z_5}$ is a homomorphism. Indeed, if $\epsilon$ is **any** reflection then we must have $2\varphi(\epsilon)=0$, and hence $\varphi(\epsilon)=0$. So all reflections are mapped to zero.

Also, if $\epsilon$ is a reflection then we have $\rho=(\rho\epsilon)\epsilon$, and hence $\varphi(\rho)=\varphi(\rho\epsilon)+\varphi(\epsilon)=0+0=0$. So all generators are mapped to $0$, thus $\varphi$ must be the trivial homomorphism.